# Validate form without submitting

Tags: javascript, html

I want to validate the form without submitting. I do not intend to refresh the page. I'm trying this way but it's not validating.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form method="POST" class="row g-3">

  <div class="col-md-4">
    <label for="Tipo" class="form-label">TIPO DE ALERTA <span style="color: red;">*</span></label>
    <select class="form-select chosen-select" name="Tipo" id="Tipo" required>
    <option selected>Selecione opções</option>
    <option value="1">Teste</option>
    <option value="2">Teste1</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <label for="Assunto" class="form-label">Assunto <span style="color: red;">*</span></label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Assunto" name="Assunto" required>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12">
    <button type="button" class="btn-wide btn btn-success" style="float: right; margin-right: 5%; margin-top: 1%;" onclick="insert_form();"> Enviar <i class="metismenu-icon pe-7s-paper-plane"></i></button>
  </div>
</form>
```

I can validate the form with js, but that way I have to put the `button` with `type="submit"`, but I don't want it to refresh the page

Comment: Don't use inline `onclick` attributes. Add the event listener using JS instead, that way you can call `preventDefault()` on the submission event.

Comment: @Chris G Would it be possible to post an example?

Comment: `document.forms[0].addEventListener('submit', function (e) { ... });` to add the event. Inside the callback function you can now do `e.preventDefault();` to prevent the submission. You can now validate `this.Tipo.value` and so on.

Comment: @Chris G But that way, when the form is filled out correctly and it does record, it will submit and update the page, correct?

Comment: No, if you want to ultimately submit the form, validate it first, then only call `e.preventDefault();` if it fails validation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use events like `onchange` or `onkeyup` to detect changes and run your validation

I wrote an example for the text input, whenever the user presses a button it runs the validate function

```js
function validate(value) {
console.log("addvalidation code here", value);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form method="POST" class="row g-3">

  <div class="col-md-4">
    <label for="Tipo" class="form-label">TIPO DE ALERTA <span style="color: red;">*</span></label>
    <select class="form-select chosen-select" name="Tipo" id="Tipo" required>
    <option selected>Selecione opções</option>
    <option value="1">Teste</option>
    <option value="2">Teste1</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <label for="Assunto" class="form-label">Assunto <span style="color: red;">*</span></label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Assunto" name="Assunto" onkeyup="validate(this.value)" required>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12">
    <button type="button" class="btn-wide btn btn-success" style="float: right; margin-right: 5%; margin-top: 1%;" onclick="insert_form();"> Enviar <i class="metismenu-icon pe-7s-paper-plane"></i></button>
  </div>
</form>
```